# What can cause a missing data issue with a POST only receiving partial data

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, post, windows-services

I have two C# applications, one is a Windows Service that reads systems and installed applications data from the PC it is installed on. The other is a Web Service that accepts a POST.
The windows service part is making the XML data as expected, and sending it using a POST as follows:

```
public Boolean SendToWeb(ConfigXMLData configData, LocalMachineData localData, LocalClientAccess localMachine)
    {
        WebRequest webRequest = null;
        WebResponse webResponse = null;
        string returnVal = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            webRequest = WebRequest.Create(configData.WebServices);
            webRequest.Method = "POST";
            webRequest.ContentType = "text/xml";
            string fileContents = SerialiseToXML(localData);
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(webRequest.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                sw.WriteLine(fileContents);
            }
            localMachine.SaveToLogFile("The Data was Sent, checking for a reply...");

            webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse();
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                returnVal = sr.ReadToEnd();
                sr.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception error)
        {
            returnVal = string.Format("Error: {0}", error.ToString());
            localMachine.SaveToLogFile("Critical Post Error: " + error.Message);
            return false;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (webRequest != null)
                webRequest.GetRequestStream().Close();
            if (webResponse != null)
                webResponse.GetResponseStream().Close();
        }

        localMachine.SaveToLogFile("Response OK, Returned Value {" + returnVal + "}");
        return true;
    }
```

The XML file this sends starts as follows:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<LocalMachineData xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <PCName>UK-IT-L-13005</PCName>
  <OPSYSVersion>Microsoft Windows NT 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1</OPSYSVersion>
  <NumberOfCPUs>4</NumberOfCPUs>
  <CPUType>32Bit</CPUType>
  <OPSYSType>64Bit</OPSYSType>
  <CPUSpeedMax>2601</CPUSpeedMax>
  <CPUSpeedCur>2601</CPUSpeedCur>
  <Serial_Number>PEBGU00WB9U2M6</Serial_Number>
  <Applications>
    <string>Cisco WebEx Meetings</string>
    <string>Adobe Flash Player 24 ActiveX</string>
…
```

The following code is used with the Upload controller in the web service:

```
    public class UploadController : ApiController
{
    // POST: api/Upload
    public IHttpActionResult Post(clientData values)
    {
        string incomingText = this.Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result; //test text in
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

The web service is hit when the windows service POST code is executed, but wasn’t populating the data type. So I added the test line to see what input this was getting, and the received text starts as follows:

```html
.0.30729.4148</string>
    <string>Universal CRT Extension SDK</string>
    <string>Visual C++ Professional Templates Resource Package</string>
    <string>Visual C++ Library CRT Appx Resource Package</string>
…
```

This data is missing the first 70 lines of the sent XML, and starts reading around two thirds of the way through line 71. It then reads the remaining 421 lines, to the end of the XML file.

The problem appears to be that the raw text is only being read by the API from line 71 of the input and onwards. E.g. the first 3,957 characters of the post  are being ignored.

If put rubbish characters in for this amount of space in the raw text, then start the XML after this the API would read it as valid XML.

Running a small test input file (less than 3,957 characters) results in the API not even being fired! It is as if it doesn't even recognise the post.

I've tested this using Postman, feeding the test data directly in through the post body, and the API seems to be just ignoring the first  3,957 characters of the post body contents.

I have no idea why this is happening, and cant seem to find anything quite like this on the web.

Any idea what is happening here?